# How to create a tree data structure and be able to view it with a TreeView

Tags: delphi

I want to write a program that works on a hierarchically organized tree data structure.
I need to have a root node and then be able to add child nodes and to move these node across the complete tree.

Is there a data structure in Delphi I can use for my algorithms and then later simply "copy" it to the GUI using a `TTreeview` component?

I suppose I need such a class:

```
type
  TMyElement = class(...)
    ElementName: String; 
    ...
    ChildElementList: TMyElementList;
    HasChildElement: Boolean; 
    ...
  end;
```

At the dots, there will be more fields and routines specific for the element. How to build up this class? And how can I conveniently add these elements to a `TreeView`, using the `ElementName` field as caption for the tree nodes?

Comment: *Is there a data structure in Delphi I can use to execute my algorithms and then later simply copy to the GUI using a TTreeview component?* No there is not, at least not built-in. Are you satisfied with that answer?

Comment: If you explain the purpose and provide more details, we might be able to provide better answers.

Comment: the Problem for me :  the GUI with just Display the Name the the relation in tree of each node , In my program I have to use the other items of the class

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know how to create a tree data structure? How does this relate to GUI?

Comment: If you need a multicolumn treeview that will allow you to display not only a caption for each ode, but also some other property values, then my best suggestion to you is [TVirtualTreeView](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview)

Answer (score 2):

So, you have two questions:

> How to build up this class?

Well, not yet focusing on the viewing-in-a-tree-view-ability, you could descent your class from `TObjectList`. Doing so, every element is capable of holding more of these object lists = elements. This approach is for example used for `TMenuItem` too.

> And how can I conveniently add these elements to a `TreeView`, using the `ElementName` field as caption for the tree nodes?

You could add an `AssignTo` method to the class so that you can "assign" the root node to the `TreeView`.

Here you have an example implementation of the whole class. Add own properties as needed.

```
type
  TElement = class(TObjectList)
  private
    FName: String;
    FParent: TElement;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TElement;
    function GetLevel: Integer;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TElement);
  protected
    procedure Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification); override;
  public
    function Add(AElement: TElement): Integer;
    procedure AssignTo(Dest: TPersistent);
    constructor Create; overload;
    constructor Create(AName: String); overload;
    constructor Create(AParent: TElement); overload;
    constructor Create(AParent: TElement; AName: String); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function HasChilds: Boolean;
    procedure Insert(Index: Integer; AElement: TObject);
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TElement read GetItem write SetItem;
      default;
    property Level: Integer read GetLevel;
    property Name: String read FName write FName;
  end;

{ TElement }

function TElement.Add(AElement: TElement): Integer;
begin
  if AElement = nil then
    Result := -1
  else
    Result := inherited Add(AElement);
end;

procedure TElement.AssignTo(Dest: TPersistent);
var
  Nodes: TTreeNodes;
  Node: TTreeNode;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Dest is TTreeView then
    AssignTo(TTreeView(Dest).Items)
  else if Dest is TTreeNodes then
  begin
    Nodes := TTreeNodes(Dest);
    Nodes.BeginUpdate;
    Nodes.Clear;
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      Node := Nodes.AddNode(nil, nil, Items[I].Name, Items[I], naAdd);
      Items[I].AssignTo(Node);
    end;
    Nodes.EndUpdate;
  end
  else if Dest is TTreeNode then
  begin
    Node := TTreeNode(Dest);
    Nodes := Node.Owner;
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
      Items[I].AssignTo(
        Nodes.AddNode(nil, Node, Items[I].Name, Items[I], naAddChild));
  end;
end;

constructor TElement.Create;
begin
  Create(nil, '');
end;

constructor TElement.Create(AName: String);
begin
  Create(nil, AName);
end;

constructor TElement.Create(AParent: TElement);
begin
  Create(AParent, '');
end;

constructor TElement.Create(AParent: TElement; AName: String);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FName := AName;
  if AParent <> nil then
    AParent.Add(Self);
end;

destructor TElement.Destroy;
begin
  if FParent <> nil then
    FParent.Extract(Self);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TElement.GetItem(Index: Integer): TElement;
begin
  Result := TElement(inherited Items[Index]);
end;

function TElement.GetLevel: Integer;
begin
  if FParent = nil then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := FParent.Level + 1;
end;

function TElement.HasChilds: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Count > 0;
end;

procedure TElement.Insert(Index: Integer; AElement: TObject);
begin
  if AElement <> nil then
    inherited Insert(Index, AElement);
end;

procedure TElement.Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification);
begin
  inherited Notify(Ptr, Action);
  case Action of
    lnAdded:
      TElement(Ptr).FParent := Self;
    lnExtracted,
    lnDeleted:
      TElement(Ptr).FParent := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TElement.SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TElement);
begin
  inherited Items[Index] := Value;
end;
```

Example usage:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRoot := TElement.Create;
  TElement.Create(FRoot, '1');
  TElement.Create(FRoot, '2');
  TElement.Create(FRoot[1], '2.1');
  TElement.Create(FRoot[1], '2.2');
  TElement.Create(FRoot[1][0], '2.1.1');
  TElement.Create(FRoot[1][0][0], '2.1.1.1');
  TElement.Create(FRoot[1][0][0], '2.1.1.2');
  TElement.Create(FRoot[1], '2.3');
  TElement.Create(FRoot, '3');
  TElement.Create(FRoot, '4');
  TElement.Create(FRoot[3], '4.1');
  FRoot.AssignTo(TreeView1);
end;
```

[image]

Filling a `TTreeView` at runtime is great fun!

Comment: Wow, just what I need. Worrying though that neither @user1769184 nor anybody else cared to vote.

Answer (score -1):

Google 'rmtreenonview'. It is a single unit which implements a non-visual TTreeView-like class--most of the methods and properties are fully compatible with TTreeView.

rmtreenonview is quick and lightweight...we use it for manipulating a bunch of tree-structured data, but write the results to a grid control for display. But, you could copy results to a TTReeView just as easily.

Oh, and it also has hash-based tree searching capability and a couple other additons.